# stop $location.path from refreshing the page

Tags: angularjs

I know this issue has been discussed several times, found it myself on stackoverflow and on google groups, but can't figure out why my app is not working correctly. the thing is, i added

> reloadOnSearch: false,

on the route, but still the page is refreshing.

my app is set to work on  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
so i'm not using any hash tags.

when i'm changing the url from :

> /dashboard/990/12/false/

to :

> /dashboard/990/12/false/0/All/Q2/0/

the page get refresh.

i'm using the following command, on my controller:

```
$location.path("new url"-);
```

how can i stop that?

Comment: The search part should be a querystring parameter, not normal url. You  have to append your parameters to querystring

Comment: Thanks @Chandermani, so you mean i should do something like /dashboard?param1=990&param=12&param3=false... then it will work? is there a way to leave the url as is make the page not refresh when i change it?

Comment: Right, that is the way. I don't think you can stop page update on url route changes, that is what SPA. If that is allowed the relationship between ng-view and the browser url is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reloadOnSearch` propriety allow you to prevent page refresh for a search and not for a route change. Search parameters are appended to the url (`http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo`) and can be handled with the `$location.search` method.

You can get the full search object with `$location.search()` or set one of its field with `$location.search('foo', 'yipee')`.

For more informations look at the official documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search

The search propriety is the only way to change the URL without reloading the page (or for AngularJS, the template and the controller).

Comment: what about the route? how should it be define in app.js? is there any way to user route change success event from stopping the page from refreshing?

Comment: You just have to add the `reloadOnSearch: false` in your route definition, nothing more. What you say is true, you can use the `$routeChangeStart` event to prevent it from changing but it's very hacky and not recommendable. Using `$location.search` is the right way in AngularJS.